# Python - joining a thread to the main thread

Tags: python, python-3.x, multithreading

Let's say a have a main thread, that has created and joined Thread 1. Thread 1 has created Thread 2. Is it possible to join Thread 2 to the main thread?

I am using a default threading library and trying to avoid creating a tree of threads by joining them all to the main one.

Comment: This doesn't make sense. I think you might have the wrong idea about what "join" means. `join`ing a thread means waiting for that thread to finish.

Comment: @user2357112 but which thread is waiting? I thought that the thread that waits is the one in which join was called, am I wrong?

Comment: @VladislavYagello: The one that calls `join` is the one that waits, yes. What are you trying to do? Are you trying to have the main thread wait for thread 2 to finish? If so, you can just call thread 2's `join` method, as long as you write your code in such a way that the main thread knows about thread 2.

Comment: Yeas, that's exactly what I am trying to do. Your approach with calling join from the main thread is obvious, but can I join Thread 2 to the main thread from Thread 1?

Comment: No, threads can't make other threads do that.

Comment: Re, "but can I join Thread 2 to the main thread...?" It sounds as if you still don't really get what `join` does. It does _nothing._ `t.join()` does nothing until thread `t` is finished, and then it returns. If thread `t` already _is_ finished, then `t.join()` does nothing, and it returns immediately. There really is no more that anybody needs to say about it.

Comment: Also note: It's never a good idea for one thread to make another thread do anything. Suppose thread X wants action A to happen in or to thread Y. If X can make action A happen without first communicating its intention to thread Y, then there's no way to guarantee that Y wil be in a state where action A is safe. But if X _does_ communicate with Y, then the simplest thing to do is for X to _ask_ Y to perform the action itself. In a nutshell: Threads should always _cooperate_ with each other. Always.